# SQL Substring from a column of strings

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table with around 100,000 articles.

Each article has a description.

short example:

| ARTIKELNR | DESCRIPTION |
| --- | --- |
| 104009400031900 | S235JRG2C+C EN 10277/10 80 x 8 mm Blanker Flachstahl |
| 104009800002950 | Werksattest nach EN 10204 |
| 105009400092360 | EN 10060 Inox Rund Ø 28 mm WNr1.4034 warmgefertigt |
| 105009400068571 | 90 mm WNr1.4404 warmgefertigt, EN 10060, geschmiedet |
| 105009400004420 | WNr1.4301 Inox Vierkantstahl 6 x 6 mm EN 10278, blankgezogen |
| 105009400008800 | WNr1.4301 Inox Band geschnitten 25 x 4 mm, Breitentol. 25 m |
| 105009400068600 | WNr1.4112 Inox Rund 8.00 mm nach EN 10088-3 + A+C+SL, gesch |
| 105009400068700 | WNr1.4301 Inox Rund 36.00 mm nach EN 10088-3, geschliffen, T |
| 105009400068800 | WNr1.4104 Inox Rund 25.00 mm nach EN 10088-3, geschliffen, T |
| 105009400010035 | WNr1.4404 Inox Vierkantstahl 30 x 30 mm, gezogen EN 10278 |

None have the same format.

What I would like to do is extract the "NORM" from the description.

So, I would like to have the following result

| ARTIKELNR | NORM |
| --- | --- |
| 104009400031900 | EN 10277/10 |
| 104009800002950 | EN 10204 |
| 105009400092360 | EN 10060 |
| 105009400068571 | EN 10060 |
| 105009400004420 | EN 10278 |
| 105009400008800 |  |
| 105009400068600 | EN 10088-3 |
| 105009400068700 | EN 10088-3 |
| 105009400068800 | EN 10088-3 |
| 105009400010035 | EN 10278 |

Comment: what sql system and what version do you use?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Standard (64-bit) v11.0.7507.2
I just do not have adminstrator rights to change the COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL

Comment: @ouboma your not altering table schema. I guess, just select doesn't require to change COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL permission. Correct me i'm wrong.

Comment: @502_Geek when i use string_split() i get this error: 'STRING_SPLIT' is not a recognized built-in function name which can be solved by changing the compatibility level. which i can't really do!

Comment: FYI, version 11 (2012) ran *completely* out of support almost 2 years ago, @ouboma . You really need to get on a recent, and supported, version sooner rather than later.

Comment: I think you forgot to mention how one should go about extracting this "Norm". You're sitting on the article format, can one assume that it's always EN<space>number<something><comma> or not etc.

Comment: As for the data, it feels like it should be being normalised before it even hits your table. If the different parts of `DESCRIPTION` mean different things then store them separately.

Comment: @ThomA I totally agree with you. But I am not resposible for getting a new version of SQL, nor do I have control over normalizing the data. I have to work with what i got. But i totally agree with you!

Comment: @siggemannen nope. sometimes it is EN<space>number<something>number, sometimes it is EN<space>number, sometimes it is EN<something>number<something>number... it varies really. but the EN is always capital and always have digits afterwards.

Comment: So how do you know when the value stops, @ouboma . You have one string with `EN 10277/10 80`, how do *you* know that `80` isn't part of the value you need?

Comment: Sounds like what you need is a list of these "NORM" values and then you can check if the value is `LIKE` your `DESCRIPTION` column as there's no pattern that can be searched for. Or, again, fix your design (that *is* the real solution here).

Comment: @ThomA good question. It is ALWAYS EN + first set of numbers. So in your case it will be EN 10277/10 the second space after the EN is where the norm stops.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257171/discussion-between-ouboma-and-thom-a).

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution leveraging SQL Server XML and XQuery functionality.

It will work starting from SQL Server 2012 onwards.

Notable points:

- `CROSS APPLY` is tokenizing *DESCRIPTION* column as XML.
- XQuery `.query()` method is looking for the "EN" token via FLWOR expression and the following token via XPath predicate `...r[position()=($pos, $pos + 1)]`.
- XQuery `.value()` method gives us a desired output string.
- `REPLACE()` function removes optional trailing comma.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, ARTIKELNR CHAR(15), DESCRIPTION NVARCHAR(1024));
INSERT INTO @tbl (ARTIKELNR, DESCRIPTION) VALUES
(104009400031900,N'S235JRG2C+C EN 10277/10 80 x 8 mm Blanker Flachstahl'),
(104009800002950,N'Werksattest nach EN 10204'),
(105009400092360,N'EN 10060 Inox Rund Ø 28 mm WNr1.4034 warmgefertigt'),
(105009400068571,N'90 mm WNr1.4404 warmgefertigt, EN 10060, geschmiedet'),
(105009400004420,N'WNr1.4301 Inox Vierkantstahl 6 x 6 mm EN 10278, blankgezogen'),
(105009400008800,N'WNr1.4301 Inox Band geschnitten 25 x 4 mm, Breitentol. 25 m'),
(105009400068600,N'WNr1.4112 Inox Rund 8.00 mm nach EN 10088-3 + A+C+SL, gesch'),
(105009400068700,N'WNr1.4301 Inox Rund 36.00 mm nach EN 10088-3, geschliffen, T'),
(105009400068800,N'WNr1.4104 Inox Rund 25.00 mm nach EN 10088-3, geschliffen, T'),
(105009400010035,N'WNr1.4404 Inox Vierkantstahl 30 x 30 mm, gezogen EN 10278');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = SPACE(1);

SELECT *
    , REPLACE(c.query('
          for $x in /root/r[text()="EN"]
          let $pos := count(root/r[. << $x]) + 1
          return data(/root/r[position()=($pos, $pos + 1)])
        ').value('text()[1]', 'NVARCHAR(30)')
        ,',', '') AS NORM
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
    REPLACE(DESCRIPTION, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
    ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c)
ORDER BY ID;
```

**Output**

| ID | ARTIKELNR | DESCRIPTION | NORM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 104009400031900 | S235JRG2C+C EN 10277/10 80 x 8 mm Blanker Flachstahl | EN 10277/10 |
| 2 | 104009800002950 | Werksattest nach EN 10204 | EN 10204 |
| 3 | 105009400092360 | EN 10060 Inox Rund Ø 28 mm WNr1.4034 warmgefertigt | EN 10060 |
| 4 | 105009400068571 | 90 mm WNr1.4404 warmgefertigt, EN 10060, geschmiedet | EN 10060 |
| 5 | 105009400004420 | WNr1.4301 Inox Vierkantstahl 6 x 6 mm EN 10278, blankgezogen | EN 10278 |
| 6 | 105009400008800 | WNr1.4301 Inox Band geschnitten 25 x 4 mm, Breitentol. 25 m | NULL |
| 7 | 105009400068600 | WNr1.4112 Inox Rund 8.00 mm nach EN 10088-3 + A+C+SL, gesch | EN 10088-3 |
| 8 | 105009400068700 | WNr1.4301 Inox Rund 36.00 mm nach EN 10088-3, geschliffen, T | EN 10088-3 |
| 9 | 105009400068800 | WNr1.4104 Inox Rund 25.00 mm nach EN 10088-3, geschliffen, T | EN 10088-3 |
| 10 | 105009400010035 | WNr1.4404 Inox Vierkantstahl 30 x 30 mm, gezogen EN 10278 | EN 10278 |

Answer (score -1):

This can be a hint:

```
SELECT 
    ARTIKELNR,
    CASE 
        WHEN CHARINDEX('EN ', DESCRIPTION) > 0 THEN
            SUBSTRING(DESCRIPTION, CHARINDEX('EN ', DESCRIPTION), PATINDEX('%[0-9/.]%', SUBSTRING(DESCRIPTION, CHARINDEX('EN ', DESCRIPTION), LEN(DESCRIPTION))))
        ELSE
            ''
    END AS NORM
FROM 
    YourTableName
```

This query assumes that "EN " followed by digits, dots, or slashes uniquely identifies the start of the NORM.

Comment: yeah but for the first artikelnr: 104009400031900 it returned only EN 1 as norm. however, I want EN 10277/10. any idea how to achieve that? thanks

Comment: I guess this could solve your issue `%[0-9]+[-/]?[0-9]*%`

Comment: @502_Geek not really. both scripts give a blank for artikelnr: 105009400068800

Answer (score -1):

In the most recent versions of SQL Server, this is actually somewhat simple with builtin functionality. YOu can use `STRING_SPLIT` to split the value, and ensure you return the ordinal positions so that you can use `LEAD` or `LAG` get the next/last delimited value and filter to your `EN` values. Finally you can use `TRIM` to remove those trailing commas:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT V.ARTIKELNR,
           V.DESCRIPTION,
           SS.value,
           LEAD(SS.value) OVER (PARTITION BY V.ARTIKELNR ORDER BY SS.ordinal) AS NextValue
    FROM (VALUES(104009400031900,N'S235JRG2C+C EN 10277/10 80 x 8 mm Blanker Flachstahl'),
                (104009800002950,N'Werksattest nach EN 10204'),
                (105009400092360,N'EN 10060 Inox Rund Ø 28 mm WNr1.4034 warmgefertigt'),
                (105009400068571,N'90 mm WNr1.4404 warmgefertigt, EN 10060, geschmiedet'),
                (105009400004420,N'WNr1.4301 Inox Vierkantstahl 6 x 6 mm EN 10278, blankgezogen'),
                (105009400008800,N'WNr1.4301 Inox Band geschnitten 25 x 4 mm, Breitentol. 25 m'),
                (105009400068600,N'WNr1.4112 Inox Rund 8.00 mm nach EN 10088-3 + A+C+SL, gesch'),
                (105009400068700,N'WNr1.4301 Inox Rund 36.00 mm nach EN 10088-3, geschliffen, T'),
                (105009400068800,N'WNr1.4104 Inox Rund 25.00 mm nach EN 10088-3, geschliffen, T'),
                (105009400010035,N'WNr1.4404 Inox Vierkantstahl 30 x 30 mm, gezogen EN 10278'))V(ARTIKELNR,DESCRIPTION)
         CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(V.DESCRIPTION,' ',1) SS)
SELECT C.ARTIKELNR,
       TRIM(',' FROM CONCAT_WS(' ',C.value,C.NextValue)) AS Norm
FROM CTE C
WHERE C.value = 'EN';
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tv7l5MjN)

In 2012 (reminder, this became *completely* unsupported in 2022) it's a little harder. You can replace `STRING_SPLIT` with a different non-builtin splitter that returns the ordinal position, such as [`DelimitedN4KSplit_LEAD`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function) (N4K as your strings appear to be an `nvarchar`). You still have access to `LEAD`, but not `TRIM`, so you'll need to use `REPLACE` and `RTRIM`. This gives you something like this:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT V.ARTIKELNR,
           V.DESCRIPTION,
           DS.item,
           LEAD(DS.Item) OVER (PARTITION BY V.ARTIKELNR ORDER BY DS.ItemNumber) AS nextitem
    FROM (VALUES(104009400031900,N'S235JRG2C+C EN 10277/10 80 x 8 mm Blanker Flachstahl'),
                (104009800002950,N'Werksattest nach EN 10204'),
                (105009400092360,N'EN 10060 Inox Rund Ø 28 mm WNr1.4034 warmgefertigt'),
                (105009400068571,N'90 mm WNr1.4404 warmgefertigt, EN 10060, geschmiedet'),
                (105009400004420,N'WNr1.4301 Inox Vierkantstahl 6 x 6 mm EN 10278, blankgezogen'),
                (105009400008800,N'WNr1.4301 Inox Band geschnitten 25 x 4 mm, Breitentol. 25 m'),
                (105009400068600,N'WNr1.4112 Inox Rund 8.00 mm nach EN 10088-3 + A+C+SL, gesch'),
                (105009400068700,N'WNr1.4301 Inox Rund 36.00 mm nach EN 10088-3, geschliffen, T'),
                (105009400068800,N'WNr1.4104 Inox Rund 25.00 mm nach EN 10088-3, geschliffen, T'),
                (105009400010035,N'WNr1.4404 Inox Vierkantstahl 30 x 30 mm, gezogen EN 10278'))V(ARTIKELNR,DESCRIPTION)
         CROSS APPLY fn.DelimitedSplitN4K_LEAD(V.DESCRIPTION,' ') DS)
SELECT C.ARTIKELNR,
       RTRIM(REPLACE(CONCAT(C.item,' ',C.nextitem),',',' ')) AS Norm
FROM CTE C
WHERE C.item = 'EN';
```

Comment: thanks but DelimitedN4KSplit_LEAD is not supported

Comment: What do you mean it's not supported, @ouboma ? YOu said you're on SQL Server v11.0.7507.2, which is 2012; `DelimitedN4KSplit_LEAD` does work on 2012. Is your database in a lower compatibility than 110?

Comment: If you *are* using a lower compatibility level, @ouboma , you can use [`DelimitedSpitN4k`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%e2%80%9ccsv-splitter%e2%80%9d-function) if you're in level 100. If it's 90 or below, you *really* need to talk to your DBA; that's SQL Server 2005 compatibility levels! YOu also should have mentioned in the question that we were limited to SQL Server 2005 compatibility; some people don't have access to such environments anymore.

Comment: the compatibility of the database is 110, but when i run your code, the first error i get is 'CONCAT_WS' is not recognized as the name of an integrated function.

Comment: Huh, I thought `CONCAT_WS` was added in 2012 for some reason, it was 2017. Well, just switch to `CONCAT` then, @ouboma ; that's not a difficult change (I would have hoped you could work that one out).

Comment: then i get this error: Invalid object name 'fn.DelimitedSplitN4K_LEAD'.

Comment: You haven't created the object then, @ouboma ; that error is telling you the problem.